# Why the result is 'scope is not defined'

Tags: javascript

I want to know why the result is scope is not defined

```
function checkscope() {
      var scope = "local scope";
      function f() {
        console.log(scope);
        scope = '123' //为什么这里不是全局变量scope,最后结果为什么是scope is not defined
      }
      return f;
    }
    var foo = checkscope();
    console.log(foo());
    console.log(scope)// 结果是scope is not defined
```

Comment: Because `scope` is scoped to inside `checkscope` and is indeed not defined outside of it?! Why would you expect it to be defined outside?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have defined it out of scope i.e. functional scope.

Please define it out of the function scope. So whenever you call your function. The scope value will be changed.

```
var scope;
function checkscope() {
  scope = "local scope";
  function f() {
    console.log(scope);
    scope = '123' //为什么这里不是全局变量scope,最后结果为什么是scope is not defined
  }
  return f;
}
var foo = checkscope();
console.log(foo());
console.log(scope)/
```

Answer (score 1):

`scope` is declared in the function `checkscope`. It ceases to exist with the `}` ending that function.

Thus it no longer exists at the point you use it.